# piping objects to select-string comes up empty

Tags: powershell, select-string

Why is this coming up empty?  I'm looking for variables related to the home directory.  Do I have to resort to findstr in these cases?  I realize that I'm piping in an object.  I'd like to be able to search all properties.  -InputOjbect is type PSObject.

```
dir variable: | select-string users
```

Expected output:

```
$                              users
HOME                           C:\Users\js
PROFILE                        C:\Users\js\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
PWD                            C:\Users\js
```

EDIT:

Here's a semi-weird answer, but I have to put in the properties I want.

```
dir variable: | select name,value | select-string users

@{Name=HOME; Value=C:\Users\js}
@{Name=PROFILE; Value=C:\Users\js\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1}
@{Name=PWD; Value=C:\Users\js}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have a misconception about the function of `Select-String`. Try `Get-ChildItem Variable: | Where-Object {$_.Value -match 'users'}`

Comment: Get-ChildItem does not show up $. This does:

`dir variable: | where {$_.Value -match "users"}`

Comment: @sunilvijendra What do you mean with "does not show up $"? Did you try the code?  BTW: `dir` is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`  ... you know that, right?  ;-)

Comment: Good point, @Olaf, though sometimes doing a string-based search in the for-display output representations of the input objects is a convenient shortcut that doesn't require knowing the objects' structure - see [this feature suggestion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).

Comment: The $ is just the last command argument.  It's not that important.

Comment: [This GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726) asks that `Select-String` with non-string input apply `Out-String -Stream` implicitly:

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work like some linux shell, I would use the following:

```
    dir variable:  |Out-String -Stream  |Select-String "users"
```

Out-string converts the object into String. (-stream:line by line)

So Select-string works like intended.

Or if we want to have objects, and not a string as result:

```
dir variable:  |where {$_.value -match "users" -or $_.name -match "users"}
```

Comment: I thinks that's a bad solution. Even if it might deliver the desired output it turns powerful objects into stupid strings.

Comment: I thought it was ok.